# How does the retention on Graphite storage schema work?

Tags: graphite, whisper

I am trying to understand how the retentions in the storage-schema.conf of Graphite work.

This is my retention configuration.

```
[prod_retention]
pattern = prod\..*
retentions = 10s:30d,1m:90d
```

Does this mean the data retention is for 120 days (30d+90d) or for just 90 days ?

Answer (score 3):

That configuration means that a rolling window of 30d will have metrics at a 10s resolution and after data points exceed 30d of age, they are downsampled to a rolling window of 90d that will have metrics stored at a 1m resolution.  These resolutions are stored in the same data file.  Your longest data retention in this file would be 90d.

The aggregation function that will be used for this file when rolling up 10s data points to the 1m resolution is defined within storage-aggregations.conf (using average/mean by default).

See configuration detailed documented here: http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config-carbon.html#storage-schemas-conf and http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config-carbon.html#storage-aggregation-conf